# Need to change header link href from Dotnetnuke 7 C#

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have one website which is in Dotnetnuke 7.
I need to change the header of the existing page link of the href.

It is showing errors like

> requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300,300italic,400italic'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I am not finding which page has this.

Is anyone know that? how can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I have checked that time I got below solutions. And it is working fine.

1. `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>`
2. `<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is part of your website's skin/theme.  So, you'll need to find it there and edit the appropriate file.

Skins usually are located in /portals/_default/skins.  The skin's files will be in a directory with a name that matches the skin's name.

If your skin is installed as a local skin, look in /protals/N, where N is the portalid of your portal.

Comment: Ok, let me check and update here. Right now thanks.

Comment: I checked, but still not any success for how to change 
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

change http to https from header section.